# Why need to use deque in Python when list can do all/most of its job

Tags: python, list, deque

When I need to use Queue/Stack functionality I just use list, and it does the job fine.
Is there any benefit of using collections.deque regarding time/space complexity?

```
lst = []
```

`lst.append(item)` - append to last

`lst.pop(0)` - pop the first item

`lst.pop(-1)` - pop the last item

`lst.insert(0, item)` - append to beginning (not traditional queue/stack functionality, but deque offers. List can also do it anyways. And I believe Python list is not like an Array in other languages where you have to relocate all the elements when inserting an item?)

Comment: Python `list` objects are implemented as array lists, so yes, `.insert(0, whatever)` has to reallocate all the elements when inserting.

Comment: So, Python list objects have efficient `.append`, amoritized constant time, but `.insert(0, item)` is O(N). On the other hand, `deque` objects are implemented as linked lists (a doubly linked list of arrays), and it has constant time append/pop from *both ends*.

Comment: BTW, this is *clearly documented* in the [`collections.deque` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque): "Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction. ... Though list objects support similar operations, they are optimized for fast fixed-length operations and incur O(n) memory movement costs for pop(0) and insert(0, v) operations which change both the size and position of the underlying data representation."